# Angular 6 service subscribe returned value showing null

Tags: angular, typescript

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.encrypted = this.enCryption(Token, data); // here this.encrypted getting null
 }

 public enCryption(token, data){
    return this.encryptionService.set(key, data).subscribe(data=>{});
 }
```

i want to reuse this enCryption() function
and i dont want no function executed this (bottom) way

```
 this.encryptionService.set(key, data).subscribe(data=>{
 this.anotherfunction(data);
 Or
 this.encrypted = data
 })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.encrypted = this.enCryption(Token, data); // here this.encrypted getting null
 }

 public enCryption(token, data){
    return this.encryptionService.set(key, data).map(data=> data.json());
 }
```

Comment: core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: this.encdecService.set(...).map is not a function
    at SupportMainComponent.push../src/app/support-main/support-main.component.ts.SupportMainComponent.enCrypt1 (support-main.component.ts:73)

Comment: Here is my encryption service
public set(keys, value):any{
    const Encrpt = new Observable(observer => {
      console.log(value)
      var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
      var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(IV');
      var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(value), key,
      {
          keySize: 256 / 32,
          iv: iv,
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
      });
      observer.next(encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.format.Hex));
      })
    return Encrpt;
  }

Comment: After encryption im getting a Hex formatted string., does this work with " .map(data=> data.json())" method ?

Comment: please add a reference for map operator using rx.js like import {map} from "rxjs/operators"; in your component and you will get your string back